# is there a way to disconnect from facebook login without calling logout

Tags: ios, session, facebook-ios-sdk, logout

Basically, I'd like to know how I can logout of my facebook session if I am in an iphone app and have connected to facebook (such that I do not have to repeatedly enter my login/password).  Normally you'd disconnect in the app somewhere like in the options, but if this is not available (i.e. anything that triggers the FBSession logout method) is there some other way to do it?

I'm guessing one could restore their phone to factory settings or something.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do that using auth.expireSession:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/auth.expireSession

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the new OAUTH2 API you can delete the cookies Facebook has created to sever the users session.  Subsequent calls to https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize will re-prompt as if no user had logged in.

Comment: what cookies to delete exactly?